# populate android list from mysql error

Tags: android, mysql, listitem

I'm new to android and I'm trying to put info from my mysql server to a listview in android. I have text and image in list item. It works if I try to add only text. The errors:

```
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rolab37.lostpet/com.rolab37.lostpet.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at com.rolab37.lostpet.DashboardActivity.connect(DashboardActivity.java:201)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at com.rolab37.lostpet.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:67)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
06-22 22:54:43.215: E/AndroidRuntime(32644):    ... 11 more
```

So here is my code:
DashboardActivity.java

```
package com.example.dashboard;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.rolab37.lostpet.library.UserFunctions;

public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {
    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    Button btnLogout;
    TextView text;
    ListView listView;
    private StockAdaptor stockAdaptor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * Dashboard Screen for the application
         * */        
        // Check login status in database
        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
        if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){
            setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            connect();


            btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

            btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                    login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(login);
                    // Closing dashboard screen
                    finish();
                }
            });

        }else{
            // user is not logged in show login screen
            Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);
            // Closing dashboard screen
            finish();
        }
    }

    private class StockAdaptor extends BaseAdapter { //The stocks list adaptor

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView name;
            TextView price;
            ImageView image; 
        }

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private StockInformation[] stocks = null; //Array of stocks
        private ListView stocksListView = null;

        public StockAdaptor(Context context) {
            super();
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public void setStockList(StockInformation[] stocksinfo) {
            this.stocks = stocksinfo;// //////////////LITERALLY THIS

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return stocks.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return stocks[position];
        }

        public StockInformation[] getAll() { //Return the array of stocks
            return stocks;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder; //New holder
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard,
                        null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                // Creates the new viewholder define above, storing references to the children
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

                stocksListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                if (holder.image != null) {
                    if (holder.image.getDrawable() == null) {
                        new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.image, null)                                 .execute(stocks[position].imageurl); //Download the image using the imageurl

                    }
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                stocksListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.name.setText(stocks[position].name);
            holder.price.setText(stocks[position].location);

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private void connect() {
        String data;
        List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,r);
        ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
          try {
              DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost/list.php");
              HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
              HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
              data=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
              Log.e("STRING", data);
              try {
                 JSONArray json=new JSONArray(data);

                 Vector<StockInformation> vstocks = new Vector<StockInformation>();
                 Log.e("debug", "aici");
                 for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                     JSONObject obj=json.getJSONObject(i);
                     StockInformation stock = new StockInformation();
                     stock.name = obj.optString("name");
                     stock.location = obj.optString("location");
                     stock.imageurl = obj.getString("imageurl");
                     Log.e("StockLog", stock.name + stock.location + stock.imageurl);
                     vstocks.add(stock);
                 }
                 StockInformation[] stocks = new StockInformation[json.length()];

                 int stockscount = json.length();
                 for (int n = 0; n < stockscount; n++) 
                 {               
                     stocks[n] = vstocks.get(n);
                 }
                 stockAdaptor.setStockList(stocks);
                 list.setAdapter(stockAdaptor);
                /* 

                 for(int i=0;i<json.length(); i++) {
                      JSONObject obj=json.getJSONObject(i);
                      String name=obj.getString("name");
                      String year=obj.getString("year");
                      String age=obj.getString("age");
                      Log.e("STRING", name);
                      r.add(name);
                      r.add(year);
                      r.add(age);
                      list.setAdapter(adapter);
                 }*/

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }

          } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
              Log.d("DashboardActivity", e.getLocalizedMessage());
          } catch (IOException e) {
              Log.d("DashboardActivity", e.getLocalizedMessage());
          }
    }

    private class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView, View view) {
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        // Actual download method, run in the task thread
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
            }

            if (imageViewReference != null) {
                ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {

                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } else {
                        //
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
            if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)){

                final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
                final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
                    final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode
                                + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                        return null;
                    }

                    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    if (entity != null) {
                        InputStream inputStream = null;
                        try {
                            inputStream = entity.getContent();
                            try {
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                                int bytesRead;
                                ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                }   
                                return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(output.toByteArray(), 0, output.toByteArray().length);
                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.i("IAE", "in stocks");
                                return null;
                            }
                        } finally {
                            if (inputStream != null) {
                                inputStream.close();
                            }
                            entity.consumeContent();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    getRequest.abort();
                    Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                } finally {
                    if (client != null) {
                        client.close();
                    }
                }
                return null;

            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

StockInformation.java
    package com.example.dashboard;

```
public class StockInformation {

    public String name;
    public String location;
    public String imageurl; 

}
```

dashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#3b3b3b">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="WELCOME"
              android:textSize="40dip"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:layout_marginTop="20dip"/>

      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
      </ListView>

    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Logout Me"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textColor="#21dbd4"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
        android:background="@null"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and dashboardlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the json

```
[{"name":"Nicu","location":"1983","imageurl":"http:\/\/www.fancyicons.com\/free-icons\/103\/flags\/png\/256\/romania_flag_256.png"},{"name":"Adina","location":"1987","imageurl":"http:\/\/icons.iconarchive.com\/icons\/custom-icon-design\/flag-3\/256\/United-Kingdom-flag-icon.png"}]
```

Hope you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because stockAdaptor in DashboardActivity on line 201 is null.

Comment: Ok and what should I do next. "stocks" looks like it has values

Comment: You should assign a value to the stockAdapter variable in the DashboardActivity's onCreate method, like: stockAdapter = new StockAdaptor(this);